# Magento manage individual products in an order

Tags: magento

I am using magento and have very specific scenario. We need to manage (that monitor, update, edit status etc.) for different product in an order. For e.g. customer order contain 3 products, each of these product might need to be handle separately. So while 1 could still be in processing stage, other might be ready to ship and other product is actually out for delivery. From a design / framework perspective what is the best option to handle such scenario.

Comment: Frankly we are still at design discussion as to what would be the best way. By default the fira thing comes to mind is to spilt each item in an order as multiple orders (sub orders). The other option is to have provision to specify status against each item and then split happen base on items which are in different statuses. Frankly looks like we are shooting in dark.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?